# How to loop through table in Selenium IDE?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have the following code which I add CART item with a coupon code, but I want to put a loop when I have for example items in the cart and it will delete my old items and insert the new items and how do I know how many items the user has

```
<td>store</td>
<td>30</td>
<td>loop</td>

<td>store</td>
<td>20</td>
<td>i</td>

<td>while</td>
<td>${i}&lt;${loop}</td>
<td></td>

<td>click</td>
<td>link=Sales</td>
<td></td>

<td>clickAndWait</td>
<td>link=Sales Panel</td>
<td></td>

<td>readCSV</td>
<td>file:\C:\Users\Numg\Desktop\webusers\web-users_1.csv</td>
<td></td>


<td>storeCellValue</td>
<td>id</td>
<td>${i},1</td>

<td>echo</td>
<td>${id}</td>
<td></td>

<td>click</td>
<td>id=web_user_user_id</td>
<td></td>

<td>type</td>
<td>id=web_user_user_id</td>
<td>${id}</td>

<td>pause</td>
<td>5000</td>
<td></td>

<td>clickAndWait</td>
<td>link=Ok</td>
<td></td>

<td>waitForPageToLoad</td>
<td>100000</td>
<td></td>

<td>click</td>
<td>id=4</td>
<td></td>

<td>pause</td>
<td>5000</td>
<td></td>

<td>select</td>
<td>id=aggrupations_639_shares</td>
<td>label=3</td>

<td>clickAndWait</td>
<td>css=#bet-group &gt; #send &gt; i.fa.fa-arrow-right</td>
<td></td>

<td>storeElementPresent</td>
<td>id=code</td>
<td>editvalue</td>

<td>echo</td>
<td>${editvalue}</td>
<td></td>

<td>gotoIf</td>
<td>${editvalue}==true</td>
<td>StepsWithEdit</td>

<td>gotoIf</td>
<td>${editvalue}==false</td>
<td>StepsWithoutEdit</td>

<td>label</td>
<td>StepsWithEdit</td>
<td></td>

<td>type</td>
<td>id=code</td>
<td>123QA</td>

<td>clickAndWait</td>
<td>css=#new_reduction &gt; input[name=&quot;commit&quot;]</td>
<td></td>

<td>label</td>
<td>End</td>
<td></td>

<td>label</td>
<td>StepsWithoutEdit</td>
<td></td>

<td>clickAndWait</td>
<td>link=Cancel</td>
<td></td>

<td>label</td>
<td>End</td>
<td></td>

<td>type</td>
<td>id=code</td>
<td>123QA</td>

<td>clickAndWait</td>
<td>css=#new_reduction &gt; input[name=&quot;commit&quot;]</td>
<td></td>

<td>clickAndWait</td>
<td>link=Clear</td>
<td></td>

<td>pause</td>
<td>5000</td>
<td></td>

<td>storeEval</td>
<td>${i} + 1</td>
<td>i</td>

<td>endWhile</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
```

This is deleted code:

```
<td>clickAndWait</td>
<td>css=input.button</td>
<td></td>

<td>clickAndWait</td>
<td>//input[@value='Delete']</td>
<td></td>

<td>clickAndWait</td>
<td>//input[@value='Delete']</td>
<td></td>
```

Comment: kindly please post this question here [stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: Here is how to loop tests in the Selenium IDE: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033321/how-to-loop-tests-in-selenium-ide

Comment: Bobby231, can you please put that link as an answer since it seems to clearly be covering looping in Selenium IDE?

Comment: @quintumnia You may not be aware of this, but this site actually was merged into the Selenium site 5 years ago. Any question relating to Selenium is on topic here.

Comment: @corsiKa That's cool! though the second comment wants the question there!

Comment: You're correct - it's fully on topic in both places.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to loop tests in the Selenium IDE:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033321/how-to-loop-tests-in-selenium-ide

From the above post:

- Download this js file: https://github.com/darrenderidder/sideflow/blob/master/sideflow.js
- Launch Selenium IDE from Firefox and open the options menu.
- Upload the .js file to the "Selenium Core extensions (user-extensions.js)" field.

The js file provides goto, gotoIf and while loop functionality in Selenium IDE.